# express req.session not populated

Tags: node.js, express, populate, supertest, cookie-session

I have an express app where I'm using cookie-session for storing jwt token. I'm using supertest to test that app.
So, here is what I'm trying to achieve:

Here a cookie is created and jwt is stored inside.

```
const request = require('supertest');

const response1 = await request(app)
            .get(`/api/users/....`)
            .expect(200);
```

Then I'm getting the cookies:

```
const cookies = response1.get('Set-Cookie');
```

Actually, there are two cookies:

```
[
      'session=eyJqd3QiOiJleUpoYkdjaU9pSklVekkxTmlJc0luUjVjQ0k2SWtwWFZDSjkuZXlKcFpDSTZJall6TlRJM01qWTNORFJpWm1Ga05qRmxORE5sTVdVME1DSXNJbWxoZENJNk1UWTJOak0wTnpZeU15d2laWGh3SWpveE5qYzBNVEl6TmpJemZRLkFzeHhjYnV6MEZobVhxOEZoRUZTV2MtVGF6MFFELXkycVhfQ0h0Q0NiX2MifQ==; path=/; expires=Fri, 21 Oct 2022 10:30:23 GMT; httponly',
      'session.sig=2yfTP5EKMbkQsrc9sfNh4ZcPbzY; path=/; expires=Fri, 21 Oct 2022 10:30:23 GMT; httponly'
    ]
```

The session cookie value is base64 encoded and contains the jwt token. So, I'm taking the session value decode it then create a new jwt token, base64 encode it and then replace just the session value. Everything else is exactly the same. So it will look like that:

```
[
      'session=eyJqd3QiOiJleUpoYkdjaU9pSklVekkxTmlJc0luUjVjQ0k2SWtwWFZDSjkuZXlKcFpDSTZJall6TlRJM01qWTNORFJpWm1Ga05qRmxORE5sTVdVME1DSXNJbWxoZENJNk1UWTJOak0wTnpZeU15d2laWGh3SWpveE5qWTJNelEzTmpNemZRLk5mRVR2WHhUVlZBRlduN1g2cHBUdDJ0ZWVWRUdUOEhyV3lOSmQtNl9RcmsifQ==; path=/; expires=Fri, 21 Oct 2022 10:30:23 GMT; httponly',
      'session.sig=2yfTP5EKMbkQsrc9sfNh4ZcPbzY; path=/; expires=Fri, 21 Oct 2022 10:30:23 GMT; httponly'
    ]
```

Let's say the new cookie is stored in a constant `const newCookie = modifiedCookie;` On the next request I set the cookie like this:

```
const response2 =await request(app)
            .patch('/api/users/...')
            .set('Cookie', newCookie)
            .send({})
```

After the last request `req.session = {}`, `req.session.isNew = true`, `req.session.isChanged = true` and `req.session.isPopulated = false`.

Any idea what causes this behavior? Why is `req.session` empty?

If I get the cookie from the previous request and send it with the new request:

```
const response2 =await request(app)
            .patch('/api/users/...')
            .set('Cookie', response1.get('Set-Cookie')
            .send({})
```

everything works just fine. `req.session` is populated with the jwt token.

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example